# How to implement "Cancel" button for a recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, recursion, cancellation

I'm trying to implement a "Cancel" button for an algorithm in a folder synchronization app. The algorithm goes recursively through a directory structure specified by the user, puts its files and directories into a TreeView, and marks them depending on whether they are new, deleted, changed, or unchanged in relation to their equivalents in the other folder. Simplified code for reference:

```
fillInTreeView(File x, TreeItem root) {
    if (x.isFile()) {
        newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
        assignMark(newBranch);
    } else {
        newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
        assignMark(newBranch);
        fillInTreeView(x, newBranch);
    }
}
```

What I'm shaky at are the implications of that "Cancel". If I make it delete everything in the tree from the top, won't the function continue to add new stuff anyway, calling itself from the files that the cancel algorithm hasn't reached yet, making the whole button pointless? I figured I'd rather ask first rather then spend several days trying to implement it, only to have to ask later and rediscover America.

Comment: algorithms don't have a UI, so you can't add a 'cancel' button. You can, however, put confirmationdialogs in there. but if the path is deep, do you really want each level to click ok or cancel?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want the cancel functionality to do? I'd imagine that it would just stop the currently-executing recursion, by doing something like @dr_debug's suggestion, but you talk about deleting files - do you mean that you want it to not just terminate the process, but also undo the changes it made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it Like this:

```
private static boolean cancelled = false;

fillInTreeView(File x, TreeItem root) {
   if(cancelled) return;
   if (x.isFile()) {
        newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
        assignMark(newBranch);
    } else {
        newBranch = makeBranch(x.getName(x.getNameCount() - 1).toString(), root);
        assignMark(newBranch);
        fillInTreeView(x, newBranch);
    }
}

/*Your CLick-Listener*/
public void onClick(){
       cancelled = true;
}
```

Comment: Please, explain a bit more what you wrote so that people understand it quickier :)

Comment: I think that line should be `if (cancelled) return`, shouldn't it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `if(cancelled) return;`? It wouldn't work anyways unless you made `cancelled` volatile. I also don't think it should be static. What happens if you are running 2 tasks at the same time.

Comment: If `if(!cancelled) return;` your recursion won't even run.

Comment: You're right i changed it to `if(cancelled) return;` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be having a return condition that simply causes the function to return that condition. By checking for this return after a recursive call you can quickly collapse even thousands of recursions.